# Different mechanisms to create google sheets

Tags: c#, google-sheets

Are there any options apart from using the Google API for creating Google sheets?

For example, with Excel, I can create them using interop, or EPPlus or by creating a spreadsheet XML format.

Comment: Unless you're a great hacker, the only way to interact with a Google product is with their approved methods: the API or the browser UI. Excel _allows_ COM interaction because it's designed that way.

Comment: Excel also supports out of the box "standard" xml formats, which basically allow you to create the data AS data, rather than some sort of stateful interaction

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The only ways to create a Google Sheet are:*

- *Programmatically using the Sheets API using the [`Spreadsheets.create()` method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create).*
- *Clicking one of the templates under `Start a new Spreadsheet` at [sheets.google.com](https://sheets.google.com).*
- *Directly visiting the `/create` endpoint at [docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create) Either in the browser or by making a programmatic HTTP request with a library such as [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)/[WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)/[HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)*
- *Following in the `File > New > Spreadsheet` menu item from an already-open Spreadsheet File in the Browser.*
- *Following the `+ New > Google Sheets` menu item at [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com) and using either the `Blank Spreadsheet` or `From a template` options.*
- *Using some third-party library such as [GSpread.NET](https://scand.com/products/gspread/) to read/write Google Sheets as normal Excel documents (not supported by Google, though these also just use the API as in the first bullet point).*

Comment: brilliant....that was the sort of thing....actually the last thing is what I was hoping would exist somewhere.

Comment: ah, actually the last one isnt quite what I'd hoped...